# Rails Ransack not filtering correctly but object status?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, search, ransack

I have an index page where I need to filter `Invoice` by it's `status` and `due_date`.

filters:

```
<%= simple_form_for :invoice_filters, { url: admin_invoices_batch_edit_index_path, method: :get } do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :status_eq, ["scheduled", "unpaid"],  { include_blank: "Invoice status..."}, class: "form-control gray" %>
  <%= f.input :start_date, as: :string, placeholder: "Start date for filter",
              input_html: { value: @start_date,
                data:{
                  controller: "flatpickr",
                  attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                }
              } %>

  <%= f.input :end_date, as: :string, placeholder: "End date for filter",
              input_html: { value: @end_date,
                data:{
                  controller: "flatpickr",
                  attributes:{ enableTime: false, enableSeconds: false }
                }
              } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Filter" %>
<% end %>
```

controller and action:

```
  def index
    @invoices = current_account.invoices.paginate(page: params[:page])
    if params[:invoice_filters].present?
      @start_date = params[:invoice_filters][:start_date]
      @end_date = params[:invoice_filters][:end_date]
      invoices = current_account.invoices
        .between_dates(@start_date, @end_date)
      search = invoices.ransack(params[:invoice_filters][:status_eq])
      @invoices = search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
    end
  end
```

I got the date filter correctly working, but as I apply a status filter to that result, it doesn't seem to do anything as it will display all invoices in the selected `due_date` range but with all kinds of `status`es.

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's got something to do with the way I'm passing params to Ransack but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing this `invoices.ransack(params[:invoice_filters][:status_eq])` to `invoices.ransack(params[:invoice_filters].slice(:status_eq))`. `ransack` needs to know the [column_name]_[predicate]. Generally this would be done via `current_account.invoices.ransack(params[:invoice_filters])` and using `start_date_gteq` and `end_date_lteq` as parameters

Comment: @engineersmnky is correct that you're doing a lot of work in your controller that ransack should be able to do for you (start_date_gteq etc). For your problem: What does params[:invoice_filters][:status_eq] hold ?

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you both. You suggestion worked! params[:invoice_filters][:status_eq] was not working because that held a string with the selected status (eg: "unpaid").

Comment: BTW I realize something like due_date_lteq and due_date_gteq would be useful for a date range filter, but I could not manage to get the inputs working  with flatpickr because I was getting an error saying that "f.input is not a Ransack helper".
I don't know what the raplacement for f.input is in a Ransack search_form_for so I kept that syntax and tried to work around the filter not working as is.